# Practice for Basic C++

Tags: c++

This is a practice question I'm having trouble answering. Anybody have a clue about the formula? I was thinking sum of the numbers as so.. 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 ... 2 ^ n ?
What is the (sign = -sign; ) used for? Thanks for anyone that can give some assistance.

Give a description of the mathematical formula that the following function computes.

```
// Pre: n>=0
// Post: ???
double WhatAmI(int n) {
    int result=0;
    int ctr=0;
    int sign = 1;
    while(ctr<=n) {
        result = result + power(2,ctr);
        sign = -sign;
        ctr++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: power series is my guess

Comment: no wait, sign is not used. you're right

Comment: `sign = -sign;` does nothing, since the value of `sign` isn't used anywhere. Either it's a red herring, or there's something missing from the code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the function calculates this formula (in a very inefficient manner I might add):

```
2^(n+1) - 1
```

Assuming of course that you meant `pow()` instead of `power()` (or at least that they do the same thing). The effect is that it creates a binary mask with `n+1` 1's in it.

```
WhatAmI(3) = 15 =   0b1111
WhatAmI(4) = 31 =   0b11111
WhatAmI(7) = 255 =  0b11111111
```

As others have mentioned, the `sign` variable appears not to be used.

This is a more efficient function that does the exact same thing:

```
double WhatAmI(int n) {
    return (1 << (n+1)) - 1;
}
```

Comment: @paddy, correct. Updated

Answer (score 1):

This is adding up powers of 2 all the way to `2^n`.

If you think about it, it's just setting every bit in the number to 1.

```
 n  | result (binary)
----+------------------------------------
 0  | 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
 1  | 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
 2  | 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111
 3  | 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111
... | ...
29  | 00111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
30  | 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
31  | 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

You can of course calculate this without a loop.

The function uses an `int` internally but returns a `double`, so it's not clear whether this is constrained to integers.  Either way, the formula is one line.  Will leave that part of the exercise to you.

Note that if you only need to deal with `ints` the operator (`<<`) is a good substitute for `pow`.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you add one to any of these numbers?